# Change color for all set borders

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Having a table with some complex borders. How can I change the border color for all borders in the table? Know I can change one by one, but that is a hassle.

For example:

```
+-----+--+
|1A 2A|3A|
|1B 2B|3B|
+-----+  |
|1C 2C|3C|
+--+-----+
|1D|2D 3D|
|1E|2E 3E|
+---...
```

I want to change color of all *set* borders, not set all borders and set it to a color.

If there is a way to set border color before drawing borders, such that when I set e.g. a box [] border they get *that* color, and all subsequent border drawing also get this color, that could also work, but have not found a way to do this either. Nor a way to have a *persistent* border style when setting borders.

Really miss MS Excel border drawing pen sometimes ...

I also tried creating the table in HTML and paste it to Calc. But as the parser in Calc is completely broken, this does not work either.

Comment: The macro-free way is to set a style (Format→Styles and Formatting) where all borders are set, with a default color. Before drawing borders, apply that style to your table (highlight the area you want affected, then double-click on the style name in the Styles and Formatting window).  The disadvantage here is that you have to remove borders from cells that shouldn't have them, but unfortunately there is no way to set a default color without turning on all the borders.  Alternately, a macro could be written to iterate through all highlighted cells and change the color of set borders.